# How to set the path to the latest Open MPI version?

Tags: path, ubuntu-14.04, openmpi

I'm using Ubuntu **14.04** and the installed Open MPI is **1.6.5**; I've installed the Latest Open MPI[(**4.0.0**)](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/) following these instructions [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building) and set the installed location by-

```
./configure --prefix=/$HOME/Downloads/openmpi
```

Then, to set the path I've added these lines to my `.bash_aliases` file-

```
om() {
    export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/bin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/lib
}
```

I've run the `om` command and then ran `mpirun --version` but it still outputs-

```
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.6.5

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

How can I keep and use both the Open MPI versions?
Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs to askubuntu.com

Comment: There's an `openmpi` tag here which isn't there on the `askubuntu` site. I'll keep this question here for a bit; will remove it if there's no response.

Comment: this answer is not ubuntu specific whatsoever, so why would the question be asked on an ubuntu only site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to append Open MPI to your paths, but prepend it.

```
om() {
    export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
}
```

Comment: That makes more sense, Thanks!